# Web like Desktop GUI in C# winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can I program a web like GUI for my Winforms Desktop Application?

For example, Visual Studio 2008 Start Page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Options:

- Use the [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9e8s203.aspx) and [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21wykkx.aspx) controls to lay out normal WinForm controls in a web-like style.
- Use the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w290k23d.aspx) control to embed HTML bits in your WinForm.
- Use the [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745781.aspx) control to embed WPF bits in your WinForm.
- Use WPF instead of WinForms for the whole UI.

Answer (score 5):

You would want to include a browser in your application.  There is a user control called [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w290k23d.aspx) that will do this for you.

Comment: Can u provide me with any web link describing this technique?

Comment: I included a link to the control, itself in my answer.  If you google for "WebBrowser Control" you will find many people talking about it.  It is a control just like TextBox that you can drop on to your form, and point it to a web page... or pass your own HTML to it... or control the DOM yourself.  Here is just one example:
http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/08/15/displaying-custom-html-in-webbrowser-control.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [WebBrowser Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w290k23d.aspx).

Here are a few resources to get you started:

- [Using the Web Browser Control in your Application](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/12/23/1330.aspx)
- **Code Project**: [A Web Browser in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/webbrowser.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Could you clarify what you mean by 'web like' JMSA? Do you mean including HTML? If so, a WebBrowser control is what you want. If you mean like clean lines, rich dialogs, gradients, fancy buttons, all that "web 2.0" interface type stuff, you should probably explore WPF instead, it can do all that and more.

The VS2008 start page is basically just an iexplore browser window reading some html (generated from xml) locally and combining that with some RSS content.

> **How the Start Page Works**
>
> The Start Page is displayed in the Web
>   browser that is available within the
>   IDE. It consists of a client-side .htm
>   page, in this case default.htm, which
>   contains a list of tabs. These tabs
>   are based on locally stored tab
>   definition files that are authored
>   using XML. When you select a tab,
>   Visual Studio reads the related tab
>   definition file for the tab. If a feed
>   is included in the tab definition
>   file, then the content for the tab is
>   downloaded from a server, as specified
>   in the tab definition file. If the
>   file does not contain a feed, static
>   content is displayed as specified in
>   the tab definition file. See Figure 1
>   below.

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290347%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Web-like can mean lots of different things.  But when I think of web-like and windows forms I think WPF.  Its much easier to create that start page using WPF than windows forms, whose look and feel are pretty much static and boring.